# How do I edit conf file when being used by Firebird service?

Tags: service, firebird, aliases

I'm playing around with Firebird and just installed the latest version (2.5) for Windows 7 (64 bit).

I have it running as a service rather than stand-alone application.

I'm wanting to alter aliases.conf and add an alias for a database, but I can't seem to alter the file. (When trying to save in Notepad++, I get a pop-up that says "Please check if this file is opened in another program.") My suspicion is that it's locked due to the Firebird service.

I opened Services from the Windows Task Manager (Services tab, then clicked "Services..." on bottom-right), selected "Firebird Guardian" (which, as I understand, manages the Firebird Services), selected "Stop Service", verified that both services have stopped, but I'm still unable to alter the configuration file.

Recommendations?

Many thanks,
Jody

Comment: Did you install Firebird into `c:\Program Files`? The probably `aliases.conf` is also located there and a regular user (the one you are logged on with) doesn't have write permissions there.

Comment: Solved it. I was missing permissions for the file.

Comment: It's not a godd idea to store "user data" in "Program Files" - you should move that elsewhere.

Comment: Just saw your comments horse - that was the problem. Thanks. Now I need to figure out how to default Administrator settings for my main login. (I have Windows 7 on my Mac and am a bit behind the curve on basic IT Admin stuff). Thanks again.

Comment: Which user data are you referring to?

Comment: The database data files for example or anything else that is not part of the actual program binaries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The Firebird `.conf` files (`aliases.conf` and `firebird.conf`) are not user files nor database files.

Answer (score 1):

Files in `Program Files` are under UAC protection, meaning you require administrator elevation to edit them. There are two ways to edit your files:

1. Start your editor as administrator (context menu, Run as administrator), then edit the file
2. Copy the file from Program Files to your documents folder, edit it and then copy it back